# Need explanation on this code with polymorphism

Tags: c++, static, polymorphism, static-methods

I stumbled uppon this code and I am quite confused on how it compiles since one of the function from A refers to static B.  Also what it's suppose to do.

where B is derived from A.

In A.h file

```
static A*   instance();
```

in B.h

```
static B* instance() { return dynamic_cast<B*>(A::instance()); }
```

in B.cpp

```
A* A::instance()
{
    static B s_instance;
    return &s_instance;
}
```

Class definitions and such were omitted to lighten the code.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `A::instance()` gives you a `A*` that points to a `B`. Always the same `B`.
- `B::instance()` gives you the result of `A::instance()`, `dynamic_cast`ed to `B*`.

There is no reason for this to cause a compilation failure (except that definitions of `A` and `B` are missing, that is).

Comment: Is there another way to do this type of thing?

Comment: @Apoc: That entirely depends on what the code is using these functions for. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Having 2 types of singletons, where one is derived from the other, but only having one instance for both types.

Comment: @Apoc: Putting the object inside `B::instance()`, and having `A::instance()` convert the pointer implicitly, would be neater and wouldn't require the types to be polymorphic. Not using a singleton at all would be even [better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975).

Comment: @Mike Seymour, well for not using the singleton, I guess I'll to read more about it and propose that to the team if I find it suitable.  That's how they've been dealing with this type of problem for quite a long time.

Comment: @Apoc What type of problem? I've never seen a need for a singleton.

Comment: In the  project it's used to shared entities among several objects.  Lets say object A,B,C,D need to make use of several Widgets. I was told to just put them in a manager (singleton), To share them.

Comment: "I was told to" is not a reason.

Comment: To someone with little experience, and who doesn't know a better alternative, I think it's fair.